# Command key in MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim

How do I use the command key in MacVim? For example I would like to be able to press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> to open CtrlP or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> to open NerdTree.

Comment: there is another same question here: http://superuser.com/questions/249448/macvim-re-map-command-key-combinations-like-d-f check it out ;)

Comment: You can browse a list of keys available in the vim via `:help key-notation`

Answer (score 17):

See `:help <D-`. Use `<D-t>` to map to <kbd>⌘-T</kbd>; **however**, <kbd>⌘-T</kbd> is already mapped to "New Tab" within MacVim's menu. You'll have to remove that to be able to use it in a Vim map.

Some keys are OS-bound and you just can't access them, but <kbd>⌘-T</kbd> can be made available and is actually the example they use in the help file (see `:help Actions.plist` and scroll up a few lines to `4.`). You'll need to unset the "New Tab" binding with

```
:macmenu File.New\ Tab key=<nop>
```

and then map <kbd>⌘-T</kbd> with `nnoremap <D-t> whatever`.

Comment: The `<D-` prefix does not seem to work with mouse events, i cannot map  `<D-LeftMouse>`.

Answer (score 6):

The command key on OS X is known as the Super key in Vim, so you can do the following:

```
map <D-t> :CtrlP<CR>
map <D-n> :NERDtree<CR>
```

You can read more about the different key mappings in `:help key-notation`. You can't use the command key as a leader because it doesn't *lead* off a command, but is instead a modifier.

Comment: ⌘ may be `M-` in other Vims, but in MacVim it's `D-`. If `'macmeta'` is set, `M-` is trigged by Option/Alt.

Comment: @WilburVandrsmith Ah you're correct, I was looking at a `<M-D-Left>` mapping in my config and picked the wrong one. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried mapping `D-`, `A-` and `M-` and they all doesn't work. I'm trying to accomplish the same thing as you which is to create aliases for `CtrlP` and `NERDTree`. How did you make it work?