# How to use command + V to enter insert mode and copy in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a method in OS X such that Vim will enter insert mode automatically and copy text, instead of having to enter insert mode first and press command + V?
Or more generically, how to map command keys in Vim in OS X? I use command line Vim, not MacVim.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command key in MacVim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979313/command-key-in-macvim)

Comment: If this is command line vim I like using http://stackoverflow.com/a/7053522/1890567 for pasting into the buffer. However you can't map anything to use command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pasting code into terminal window into vim on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585129/pasting-code-into-terminal-window-into-vim-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your vimrc:
`nnoremap <c-v> p:startinsert!<cr>`

This will insert your clipboard content and place the cursor after the inserted text and change to insert mode.

But why you want insert mode altogether? Just press `p` in normal mode!